# SharePoint 2010 List, Current User Location selection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, list, list-view

In a SharePoint 2010 List, I have a list that has a column of "Location of work" which is based on country.

I want to create a Custom View, with a filter that should work like

> **Every current User can only view the list items that have the same work location as the current User's.**

I am trying to work this out as an OOTB solution by modifying the view.

Is there a way I can select the current user's country in the part where I typed `[Me]`  (obviously the [Me] was a desperate attempt), but is there a simple function I can write there for the current requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there are no OOTB filter functions other than `[Me]` and `[Today]`

- **[Me]** denote to the current user.
- **[Today]** denote to the current today date

Answer (score 2):

If this information is stored in their user file, you can add a context filter to the view page.

1. Add Context filter web part to view page.
2. Configure the filter to filter on the current user profile
3. Configure the filter to return the "Country" value from the user's profile
4. Connect the filter web part to the list web part.